# Reading data from txt file into vectors

Tags: c++, vector, fstream

I tried to use `vectors` instead of arrays in one of the parts of my program, because of other problems. I have never really used them previously.

This is the part of the code:

```
#include <vector>

ifstream file("data.txt");
vector<int> beds;
vector<int> people;
vector<int> balconies;

while(!file.eof()){
    file >> people.push_back();
    file >> beds.push_back();
    file >> balconies.push_back();
}
```

I have no idea if it would be working. Anyway now I have an error: `No matching member function for call to 'push_back'`.

Comment: You can't learn C++ by trial and error, or throwing bits of code together without understanding them. Where are you learning this?

Comment: Read the documentation for the proper use of `push_back`. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `std::vector::push_back` accepts an argument, which is the value to add to the end of the vector. So you need to break each of those calls into two steps: first read the value into an `int`, then `push_back` that value into the vector.

```
while(!file.eof()){
    int temp;
    file >> temp;
    people.push_back(temp);
    file >> temp;
    beds.push_back(temp);
    file >> temp;
    balconies.push_back(temp);
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, I would suggest against your `while` condition as written. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons) explains why in detail, along with providing better alternatives.

Comment: You might also want to mention the problem with `while (!file.eof())`. +1.

Comment: @PeteBecker Good idea, added a blurb about that with a relevant link.

Answer (score 1):

Store input data inside a variable before and then push that variable

```cpp
int example;
file >> example;
people.push_back(example);
```

or use **std::istream_iterator**